# ffmpeg how to mix 2 RTP streams that individually start and stop randomly?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to do this:

ffmpeg listens to 2 incoming rtp streams, and continuously send those mixed together to a single outgoing rtp stream

However, the 2 incoming streams are going to be starting and stopping randomly and independently of each other, as they have audio.  They don't send audio silence, they stop sending when there is silence and then they start sending again when there is audio.  ffmpeg seems to error on this situation.

I have this:
ffmpeg -i rtp://0.0.0.0:11000 -i rtp://0.0.0.0:12000 -filter_complex amix -f rtp rtp://10.10.10.10:13000

This is what happens with ffmpeg:
It wait for the audio to start, and then it sends to the output.  But, when the input stop sending, I get this error:
rtp://0.0.0.0:11000 Unknown error
rtp://0.0.0.0:12000 Unknown error

and it crashes.

How can I keep it active even when one or the other input isn't sending, and how can I prevent it from crashing?

If ffmpeg outputs silence all the time when it doesn't receive anything, that would be acceptable too.

Comment: Ffmpeg does not support this.